# Using R to Gsub search for *

Tags: r, gsub

Someone else must have had this issue but I couldn't find another user posting the question so I will.

```
v <- gsub( "*" , "" , "All Large Firms*" )
```

I want v to be "All Large Firms"  but it is not recognizing the "*" as text

Comment: Have a look at the `fixed` argument in `gsub()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to escape the `*` as it is a special character which means 0 or more characters.  When we escape (`\\`), it will regarded as any other character.

```
gsub( "\\*" , "" , "All Large Firms*" )
```

Or we can place it inside the square brackets

```
gsub( "[*]" , "" , "All Large Firms*" )
```

Or as @Richard Scriven suggested, `fixed=TRUE` argument (which would be fast) can be used as well if you just want to remove the `*` and is not using any other regex pattern

```
gsub( "*" , "" , "All Large Firms*", fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: Can't you just use `fixed = TRUE`?

Comment: @RichardScriven Yes, it can be used as well.  But, suppose if there is other regex to be used along with, it may not work well. For example, `gsub( "*|\\s+" , "" , "All Large Firms*", fixed=TRUE )`

Comment: This is just off of memory but I do believe that if you can used fixed=TRUE that it is faster than using an equivalent regular expression obtained via escaping.